# Netty server receives two separate requests instead of one

Tags: java, netty

I am making a Netty Http server, and I'm running into a problem. Whenever I send a request from a browser or a java program, it sends it twice (and yes, I am using `HttpObjectAggregator` in my pipeline.) For example:

```
INFO: [id: 0x8f2a1b64, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080] READ: [id: 0x006ab104, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62690]
Jul 19, 2017 12:52:58 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelReadComplete
INFO: [id: 0x8f2a1b64, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080] READ COMPLETE
Jul 19, 2017 12:52:58 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRead
INFO: [id: 0x8f2a1b64, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080] READ: [id: 0xbf604bb0, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62691]
Jul 19, 2017 12:52:58 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelReadComplete
INFO: [id: 0x8f2a1b64, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080] READ COMPLETE
message: testmesstwoo
HttpObjectAggregator$AggregatedFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0, components=0))
GET /?message=testmesstwoo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
content-length: 0s
Send failed2: null

//This is where the second request is:

no message
HttpObjectAggregator$AggregatedFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0, components=0))
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/?message=testmesstwoo
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
content-length: 0s
Send failed2: null
```

This all comes from one browser request.

Here is my handler channelRead method:

```
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) { // (2)

        if(!(msg instanceof HttpRequest)) {
            System.out.println("not http");
            System.out.println(msg.toString());
            System.out.println(msg.getClass());
            //ctx.write("hi");
            return;
        }

        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) msg;
        QueryStringDecoder queryStringDecoder = new QueryStringDecoder(request.getUri());

        Map<String, java.util.List<String>> params = queryStringDecoder.parameters();
        try {
        System.out.println("message: "+ params.get("message").get(0));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("no message");
        }

        ByteBuf bytes = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("test", CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        DefaultFullHttpResponse resp = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK,bytes);
        resp.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        //resp.addHeader(, buffer.readableBytes());
      //ctx.writeAndFlush("hi");
      //ChannelFuture cf=ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Ack", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        System.out.println(msg+"s");
        HttpUtil.setContentLength(resp, 4);
        ChannelFuture cf=ctx.writeAndFlush(resp);
        System.out.println("Send failed2: " + cf.cause());
    }
```

This has really stumped me, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more code.

EDIT:

Here is my pipeline:

```
          //p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
          // Uncomment the following line if you don't want to handle HttpChunks.
          p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
          p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));

          //p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
          // Remove the following line if you don't want automatic content compression.
          //p.addLast(new HttpContentCompressor());
          p.addLast(new Handler());
```

Comment: Can you show your pipeline builder ?

Comment: @Nicholas added

Comment: "Whenever I send a request from a browser or a java program, it sends it twice"  it doesn't. The second request requests `GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1`. Browsers do that automatically.

Comment: When I make a java http connection this happens: `no message
DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)), version: HTTP/1.0, content: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0))
GET /bad-request HTTP/1.0s
Send failed2: null`. What is the meaning of that?

Comment: ^the above is the second request. The first one works and outputs as expected but immediately after this happens

Comment: @tkausl is correct. The browser is automatically requesting favicon. You can add a handler to sniff out requests for that and return a 404, or return an icon.